# Determine file or directory from string

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm trying to extract some files from a Zip file, but the `FastZip.ExtractZip` method I was using is having some issues, for example:

```
Output location: C:\testing\output\

File 1: PhysicalMemory/idx - this is a file, but is created as a directory
File 2: c:/pagefile.sys/00000052 - This is a directory, but is created as a file
File 3: c:/pagefile.sys/00000052/index - This is a file, but is created as a directory
```

I'm not sure how to correctly identify these as files or directories, as some of the files don't have file extensions, which the FastZip package seems to use to identify files.

The `ZipEntry` class has a `isDirectory` method, but it's returning false for every entry, so I can't use that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: How do YOU know these entries are wrong?  How are you going to write code that determines which entry is right or wrong?  Either way, I suspect you are going to have to modify the Zip library you are using.

Comment: Some code might be useful.

Comment: I know the correct path as I've got a full listing of the contents of the zip

Comment: You can [see how this is implemented](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/4f541a404f324bd882bc1e8ecd1182c05909b08a/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/ZipEntry.cs#L1202-L1214). It expects the entry to end in `\ ` or have certain attributes. Have you tried the built-in [`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: You have a `pagefile.sys` that is a folder ??

Comment: Yes, pagefile.sys in this instance is a directory.  The zip contains data taken from a RAM snapshot

Answer (score 1):

Write your own is directory method to establish file or directory

```
    public bool isDirectory(string path)
    {
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(path);

    if (attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not that confident this will solve it given the [current implementation](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/4f541a404f324bd882bc1e8ecd1182c05909b08a/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/ZipEntry.cs#L1202-L1214) appears to do something equivalent.

Comment: Good idea, but this requires the file to already be on disk in order for it to be checked.